# drag n drop like functionality using python

Tags: python-3.x

Anyone help in achieving this kind of functionality using python please.

In the below picture we can drag the words and drop in the fill in blanks section.

here is the link:

https://www.education.com/open-interactive/worksheet/photosynthesis-fill-in-the-blank/

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
sai

Comment: This question is *way* to broad. Select a UI library like tkinter or pygame, or a webframework to create a website, and update the question once you have a minimally functional application and you have made an attempt and failed to add drag n drop. tkinter specfically has quite a few resources on this topic already.

Comment: in browser you probly need javascript for it.  with jinja or htmx you can create web page but for drag and drop probably need some js framework